# How do I write RSpec tests that require an OAuth2 access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm writing RSpec tests for a Rails API that is partially protected with OAuth2. I need to write tests such as

- `GET ResourcesController#index`

  - when `access_token` is provided

    - shows a list of resources
  - when `access_token` is not provided

    - returns no content

and stuff like that. I thought I could use the [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem, but I soon realised that that works by issuing actual HTTP requests to the Rails app. I'm a little lost, can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT** Some further info

I'm using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) to implement OAuth2. My question has to do with the fact that some methods of my controllers are hidden behind something like the following:

```
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, only: [:update, :destroy]
```

which verifies the presence, and validity, of an authentication token. Now, these tokens have to exist in the database. My question then is how do I, either

- put these tokens in the database (aka, how do I simulate a correct login within a RSpec test), or
- trick Doorkeeper (via stubbing?) to think that these tokens exist and are valid?

**EDIT 2**

Found [this](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-protected-controllers). Feel free to keep adding answers while I read this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem, it has many examples of stubbing acces tokens in [its own test suite](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/spec/oauth2/access_token_spec.rb). Without a specifically pointed issue that you might be having it's hard to give more advice though.

Alternatively, there is [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem which records http interactions and plays them out during testing. You could record your live API interactions and then use the playback to run your tests against.

**UPDATE**

After you mentioned the Doorkeeper and found its docs yourself, here is an example from the [same source](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-protected-controllers).

```
describe Api::V1::ProfilesController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    let(:token) { double :acceptable? => true }

    before do
      controller.stub(:doorkeeper_token) { token }
      # allow(controller).to receive(:doorkeeper_token) {token} # => RSpec 3
    end

    it 'responds with 200' do
      get :index, :format => :json
      response.status.should eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

> Stubbing :acceptable? => true will bypass the doorkeeper filter, since the token is valid. If you prefer to return false then the response status will be 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Thanks Nic. I had seen those examples, but I could not work out how to reuse them in my tests. I added some details to my question, hopefully that clarifies my position.

Comment: OK, I get how I can simulate the token to be valid, but what if I want to make sure that my controllers aren't misbehaving when the token is not valid, or is valid for a user that is not authorised to perform certain actions?

Comment: Meaning that I have to move the `let(:token)` and `before do` parts inside a, say, context, right? In which case, I guess my next question will be for the developers of Doorkeeper – as in, if `acceptable?` returns `false`, the controller receives `accessible?`, what is the semantic of that?